# Comparing elements between elements in two lists of tuples

Tags: python

Here is what I am looking to do.I have two list of tuples. Build a list of elements such that the first element in a tuple in list1 matches the first element in a tuple in list 2

```
list1 = [('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('z', 5)]

list2 = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]

list3 = ['a','b']
```

Note: There can be no duplicate first elements

After looking at python list comprehensions, this is what I have done

```
[x[0] for x in list1 if (x[0] in [y[0] for y in list2])]
```

My questions is would this be how an experienced python programmer would code this up? Having coded this up myself I still find this fairly hard to read. If not how else would you do it

Comment: Should `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `['a', 'c']` match `'c'`?

Comment: I would say yes the final list would be ['a', 'c'], but in my example I am specifically looking at lists of tuples

Comment: Can you explain, what "a tuple" is?  I don't understand a word you say about what you want to accomplish...

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use `zip()`:

```
In [25]: l1 = [('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('z', 5)]

In [26]: l2 = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]

In [27]: [x[0] for x,y in zip(l1,l2) if x[0]==y[0]]
Out[27]: ['a', 'b']
```

**EDIT:** After reading your comment above it looks like you're looking for something like this:

```
In [36]: [x[0] for x in l1 if any(x[0]==y[0] for y in l2)]
Out[36]: ['a', 'b']
```

or using `sets`:

```
In [43]: from operator import itemgetter

In [44]: set(map(itemgetter(0),l1)) & set(map(itemgetter(0),l2))
Out[44]: set(['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: Dang! beat me to it by 30 seconds. Note: Would increase performance by `zip`ing outside the list-comprehension so that the `zip` isn't recomputed every time

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I think the `zip()` is only called once, take a look at the byte code.

Comment: ahh thank you, anyway to make this work if the lists are of unequal lengths?

Comment: @sidg11 take a look at `itertools.izip_longest()`.

Comment: This does somethiing else than the original code because it only fins matches in matching positions.  @sidg11, could you please clarify what you want to do?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I added solution for both.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think he's actually looking for the second solution, using `any()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: That's what I think, too, but than I would suggest using sets to avoid the quadratic runtime.

Comment: @sidg11 added that to the solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)s here:

```
set(x[0] for x in list1).intersection(y[0] for y in list2)
```

or using syntactic sugar:

```
{x[0] for x in list1} & {y[0] for y in list2}
```

Both of which result in:

```
set(['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is probably clearer to use sets here (since you have no duplicate elements):

```
set1 = set( el[0] for el in list1 )
set2 = set( el[0] for el in list2 )
set3 = set1 & set2 # set intersection
# list3 = list(set3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the set intersection of the first elements of the tuples, you can use the dictionary key views introduced in Python 2.7:

```
dict(list1).viewkeys() & dict(list2).viewkeys()
```

This will be much more efficient than your solution for long lists, since it has linear runtime (as opposed to O(mn) for your solution), but returns the result in arbitrary order (as opposed to the order defined by `list1`).

In Python 3.x, this would be

```
dict(list1).keys() & dict(list2).keys()
```